# Raphaël and selecting many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, sizzle

I need to put on the page a few spinners, which are generated by Raphaël. But I can create only one spinner, because Raphaël select elements by id. How I can select many elements for example, by classes? I try use jQuery:

```
var spinners = $('div.spinners');
var r = Raphael(spinners, 320, 200);
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a small fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vSZ58/2/

1. Here we are attaching `getByClass`, spinner method to paper object.
2. While `spinner` method creates the element, we are assigning class
   attribute to the node of the element.`stick.node.setAttribute("class" , classname)`
3. Then in `getByClass` method, we are looping all the elements on the
   paper and checking whether the passed classname is there in the
   element node.if yes its pushed to `res` array, which will be the
   result.

*Note*:This method works only for the elements created with Raphael. Since you are generating spinners with Raphael it wont be a problem.

If you a declaratively defined some spinners on the svg document,i think its dont possible. If you have any idea on this please update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery each method:

```
$('div.spinners').each(function(index) {
    //alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
    var r = Raphael(this, 320, 200);;
});
```